# How to restore xserver?

Tags: xorg, nvidia

I have recently killed xserver on my machine after a regular update. I have uninstalled and reinstalled

```
nvidia-current
```

with no success. Looks I have reinstall xserver. How do i achieve this?

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it turns out there was some issue with my nvidia-current running the following command managed to get me back to non-accelerated gui, where I was then able to reinstall nvidia-current through the gui.

From the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

Then reinstalled nvidia driver through Ubuntu setup.

Comment: that's the real issue, other answers just getting the problem even worse.

Answer (score 9):

**Method : 1**

One easy way to reinstall the X server is to:

> ```
> Restart the PC with the live ubuntu disk.   
> Choose safe graphics mode.  
> Open a terminal  
> cd to /etc/X11  
> cp xorg.conf to /media/usbdrive  
> open gftp  
> upload the xorg.conf file to a server  
> restart PC without the live disk  
> ctrl-alt-f1  
> login 
> cd /etc/X11  
> sudo rm xorg.conf  
> then wget www.yourserver/xorg.conf  
> startx
> ```

You will be able to start X without a hitch because the live cd in safe graphics mode automatically determined your X settings.

---

**Method : 2**

If you just need working configuration, not the whole Xserver?
then, 
backup your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`
and do

> ```
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
> ```

---

**Method : 3**

If you really need to reinstall whole Xserver, try

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg

Enjoy!

Comment: I tried all of these it still doesn't want to bring back my xserver still booting in tty mode

Comment: just try Ctrl+Alt+7..  or Ctrl+Alt+Backspace

Comment: "Unable to locate package xserver-org"

Answer (score 5):

This actually worked for me.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Some of my nvidia drivers were not up to date. I didn't know there were more than one nvidia driver to update.

Comment: This worked for me Thank ! xfce4 and gnome on xorg did not work. I added `sudo apt install xorg xauth ubuntu-desktop xfce4`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg
```

made the wallpaper and mouse visible. But to see everything else I had to use

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

this made me reach the log-in page. If it happened that the machine didn't recognize your password, make sure `/tmp` is writable by everyone. It should also have the sticky bit (leading `1` in octal)

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```