# Ubuntu 12.04 graphical interface is gone

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, xserver

I was trying to set up my build environment for beagleboneblack.I was following standard instructions from this site

```
    https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html
```

I was installing required packages one by one. Now after reboot, GUI is gone. It is giving a message with some options that I can't select through keyboard or mouse. Doing a escape takes me to a CLI. I tried this

```
 sudo services lightdm start
```

and

```
 sudo startx
```

but nothing happens.I remember while installing this one

```
  libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

or this one

```
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos
```

It was removing x server things then again setting up.
What can I do now?
P.S.
Also while installing libgl1-mesa-glx, it said something like this

```
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.4)
  Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2)
```

So I did this

```
 sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restore xserver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21309/how-to-restore-xserver)

Comment: yes. I reinstalled nvidia driver. Now I can't log in. After giving my password a blank screen comes and then again same login screen.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: I did some things, but in the end I installed new root partition. This is the problem with linux distros. You have to first learn various types of bug fixes before indulging in what you really intended to do.

Comment: So you are OK now ?

Comment: yes, installing root partition made me to install every package again but everything is ok for now.