# Reverting "pkill Xorg"?

Tags: grub2, gnome, xorg, laptop, kill

While debugging an unrelated error, I was told to run "pkill Xorg" which has rendered my Linux installation absolutely useless as I cannot use the keyboard or mouse to do anything -- I tried opening up a TTY with the Ctrl+Alt+F* keys and the other keyboard shortcuts described online, but it looks like I cannot literally do anything. I know I can likely use my Live CD drive and redo my Ubuntu installation and start from scratch, but the installation of individual drivers on this laptop took days, and if I could forego doing that again using commands that directly reset "pkill Xorg"  I would be incredibly ecstatic

Note: I am running the latest kernel version of Ubuntu, 5.2 -- Linux my laptop will not work correctly without this update

Answer (score 1):

When you ran `pkill xorg` you killed your screen and input devices running in RAM only.

When you reboot Xorg should load again normally because programs on disk which you did not delete are loaded into RAM once again.

Comment: I've rebooted my machine but it's still the same problem

Comment: Does your keyboard work properly at grub menu? You mentioned console mode does your keyboard work to type your user ID and password there?

Comment: If you can log into console you can reinstall from there. Read the answers posted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/21309/how-to-restore-xserver I'm still not sure reinstalling Xorg is the easiest solution though.

Comment: None of that worked so I ultimately decided to just reinstall Ubuntu.