# Thinkpad Yoga keyboard stopped working (16.04)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, keyboard, xorg

This morning when I brought Ubuntu our of sleep/suspension mode, the keyboard didn't work. This is a ThinkPad Yoga 15. The mouse pad works. If I plug a USB keyboard in, it works. I've tried the solutions posted here:

[How to restore xserver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21309/how-to-restore-xserver)
[Updated from 16.04 to 16.10; the keyboard and mouse no longer works after getting to the lock screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908918/updated-from-16-04-to-16-10-the-keyboard-and-mouse-no-longer-works-after-gettin)

Which consists of:

Getting rid of NVIDIA drivers
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*

Reinstalling the desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg

And I also tried reinstalling Ubuntu drivers
apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
and
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Are there any other tricks out there??? How can I solve this silly issue? I've had it before but the above tricks worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is an actual answer, but I got the keyboard working again. I read another post where a ThinkPad user had to unplug his battery to get the keyboard working again. He thought it was something to do with his BIOS.

As an experiment, I just unplugged my ThinkPad and let the battery run down. Ubuntu shut itself down, and wouldn't reboot because the battery was critically low. I let the system sit for a little while then plugged it in and booted. At that point the mouse pointer didn't appear, nor did the keyboard work, but the touch screen did work. I rebooted again and now everything is back to normal. Odd...

I wonder how it will behave after the next reboot.